# Informix, MySQL and Oracle blob contains

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, hibernate, informix

We have an application that runs with any of IBM Informix, MySQL and Oracle, and we are using Java with Hibernate to connect to the database. We will store XML, CSV and other text-based files inside the database (clob column). The entities in Java are `byte[]` objects.

One feature request to the application is now to "grep" content inside the data. So I need to find all files with a specific content.

On regular char/varchar fields I can use `like '%xyz%'`, but this is not working on byte[] / blobs.

The first approach was to load each entity, cast the `byte[]` into a string and use the `contains` method in Java.  If the use enters any filter parameters on other (non-clob) columns, I will apply those filters before testing the clob in order to reduce the number of blobs I have to scan.

That worked quite well for 100 files (clobs) and as long as the application and database are on the same server. But I think it will get really slow if I have 1.000.000 files inside the database and the database is not always in the same network. So I think that is not a good idea.

My next thought was creating a database procedure. But I am not quite sure if this is possible for Informix, MySQL and Oracle. And I am not sure if this is possible.

The last but not favored method is to store the content of the data not inside a clob. Maybe I can use a different datatype for that?

Does anyone has a good idea how to realize that? I need a solution for all three DBMS. The application knows on what kind of DBMS it is connected to. So it would be okay, if I have three different solutions (one for each DBMS).

I am completely open to changing what kind of datatype I use (BLOB, CLOB ...) — I can modify that as I want.

Note: the clobs will range from about 5 KiB to about 500 KiB, with a maximum of 1 MiB.

Comment: How big is each BLOB/CLOB object?  KiB, MiB, GiB, bigger?  The larger the objects and the more of them there are, the worse it is to return each of the objects to the client code to see whether it should be used or not — so you're right to be worried.  Making sure the filtering is done server-side will be crucial.

Comment: Each entry will be about 5kb up to 500kb. maximum 1mb per file. And if the use enters any filter parameters, I will filter before in order to reduce the number of blobs I have to scan

Comment: Most databases will have some sort of functionality for free-form Google-like searches of unstructured text data.  You'd almost certainly want to store the data in a `clob` column rather than `blob` since it is character not binary data.  You'd then be building some sort of text index (in Oracle, the functionality you're looking for is Oracle Text).  But each database's implementation is going to be rather unique, that's not something that you're going to query with ANSI standard SQL.

Comment: Even at 5 KiB an entry, processing 1,000,000 entries client side would require 5 GiB of data over the wire.  That's fairly expensive.  So, filtering first is crucial.  Ideally, you should filter the blob server-side, not client-side.  It still has to haul up to 5 GiB of data off disk, but at least it doesn't all have to go over the server-client network connection.  Are you looking for a solution that will work with all 3 DBMS, or what?

Comment: Yes, I need a solution for all three DBMS. The application knows on what kind of DBMS it is connected to. So it would be okay, if I have three different solutions (one for each DBMS).

Comment: For filtering informix CLOB columns, maybe you can try using the [Basic Text Search](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.dbext.doc/ids_dbxt_175.htm) extension.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Apache Lucene or other text indexing library.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search

If you go with a DB specific solution like Oracle Text Search you will have to implement a custom solution for each database.  I know from experience that Oracle Text search takes significant time to learn and involves a lot of tweaking to get just right.

Also, if you use a DB solution you would receive different results in each DB even if the data sets were the same (each DB would have it's own methods of indexing and retrieving the data).

By going with a 3rd party solution like Lucene -- you only have to learn one solution and results will be consistent regardless of the Db.